# Symfony, how to define homepage route

Tags: symfony

I created a `HomeController` to show my homepage

```
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/{page?}', name: 'home')]
public function index(PostRepository $pr, EntityManagerInterface $em, $page, ): Response
    {
…
}
}
```

So far so good. But this stops working when I create a second page because it will always be catched by the home route.

For example my security controller always get's redirected to home when called with path('app_login')

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
```

It seems like the home route is too greedy and catches almost everything.

Comment: Give your `home` route a [lower `priority`](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority).

Comment: Why would you create a 'home' route that can match any URL? Is poor design in any case, but if you want to keep it this way, at least give it the lowest possible priority so it's evaluated last.

Comment: Probably you want to do just this : `#[Route('/', name: 'home')]`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to create requirements for your route param. Without it your home route will match any request that start with `/` followed by a string.

```php
#[Route('/{page?}', name: 'home', requirements={"page"="\d+"})]
public function index(PostRepository $pr, EntityManagerInterface $em, $page = 1): Response {
//…
}
```

I'm not very sure how to handle that `?`, with a default value I think you don't need it anymore.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameters-validation